# JAVA R integration, R package Issues

Tags: java, r, docker, rjava

I have a spring boot application which is calling Rscript using Rcode and while running it on a Windows machine it is working properly, I'm trying to dockerize it.

In my docker container, I'm getting the below error.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.rcaller.exception.ExecutionException: R command failed with error. Reason: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’:
 object 'as.xts' not found whilst loading namespace 'data.table'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
```

Tried multiple options like setting environmental variables, checking R compatibility issue.

I'm new to R, how to make sure all the required R packages are properly installed?
Not finding any workaround.

Your suggestions will be very much appreciated.